# What does this code segment do?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

This program is a student database. And this part of the code stores the student majors (Computer Science and Information Technology). I can't figure out what the code does though. I've never come across this format in dynamic memory allocation. Okay, is the first line a pointer to an array? And what about the pointer in the second line?

```
    string ** major;
major = new string*[3];
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    major[i] = new string[2];

major[0][0] = "IT";
major[0][1] = "Information Technology";

major[1][0] = "CS";
major[1][1] = "Computer Science";
```

Comment: It's a dynamic array - 3 "rows" by 2 "columns" where each element is a `string`. Note that it's not good C++ though, stylistically, as it's using bare C style arrays, rather than a proper type such as vector, so it has all the old C problems of potential memory leaks, etc.

Comment: I think a C++ manual/tutorial (good lists here on SO too) about pointers and memory allocation will help you much more than a short answer on StackOverflow.

Comment: @PaulR I think it would be worth mentioning that it **is not** an array, but it attempts to **emulate** one.

Answer (score 15):

> What does this code segment do?

It elaborately rapes common C++ programming idioms and systematically undermines the security of your code. It does so by needlessly resorting to raw pointers instead of using a standard container object such as `std::vector`.

> Okay, is the first line a pointer to an array?

No, a pointer to array looks like this:

```
int (*ptrToArr)[128];
```

What you have is a pointer to pointer.

> And what about the pointer in the second line?

Nothing special. It's just the type of object that `new` will allocate.

Answer (score 4):

Here it is

```
string ** major; // Create a variable that *could* be used like a 2 dimensions array
major = new string*[3]; // Allocate the first dimension
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    major[i] = new string[2]; // Allocate the second dimension

// Add some values
major[0][0] = "IT";
major[0][1] = "Information Technology";

major[1][0] = "CS";
major[1][1] = "Computer Science";
```

Hope that could help you to understand.

Answer (score 2):

that code is horrible.

first it hides semantics behind some magic index numbers --> use structure/class to organize data

```
struct CourseDetails{
  std::string name;
  std::string abbrev;

  // default constructor
  CourseDetails(){}

  // constructor that inits variables
  CourseDetails(const std::string& i_name, const std::string& i_abbrev)
  : name(i_name)
  , abbrev(i_abbrev)
  {}
};
```

second it uses error prone manual memory management -> use c++ containers.

```
std::vector<CourseDetails> major;
major.push_back(CourseDetails("Information Technology", "IT"));
major.push_back(CourseDetails("Computer Science", "CS"));

std::cout<< major[0].name << "/" << major[0].abbrev<< std::endl
```

if you do not want to define a type you may use std::pair;

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> CourseDetails; // first = name, second = abbreiation
std::vector<CourseDetails> major;
major.push_back(CourseDetails("Information Technology", "IT"));
major.push_back(CourseDetails("Computer Science", "CS"));

std::cout<< major[0].first<< "/" << major[0].second<< std::endl
```

Answer (score -5):

First line is pointer to an arrary of string pointers. In second line, this code is allocating memory (string pointers type) to "major". In loop this code is allocating memeory(string type) to every member(pointer) in "major" array.